# How to Block Spammy Accept-Language in either Apache or Nginx

Tags: apache-http-server, nginx, spam-prevention, google-analytics

Stevie-Ray has create a neat Nginx Referral Spam configuration file to block out known referrer spam on Google Analytics.
https://github.com/Stevie-Ray/referrer-spam-blocker

Sure it's a cat and mouse game, but it definitely does help.

Now it seems that the spammer are using the Accept-Language header to spam Google's overview page with things like:

```
Secret.ɢoogle.com You are invited! Enter only with this ticket URL. Copy it. Vote for Trump!
```

And

```
o-o-8-o-o.com search shell is much better than google!
```

Is there a way, either in Nginx or Apache, that you could block out Accept-Language headers that do not match the [Language Tag pattern defined by W3](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/language-tags/)?

Comment: What kind of problem is this creating? A lot of Google Analytics referral spam doesn't hit the web server, it hits GA directly.

Comment: That's true Tim, however we use Google Tag Manager so we don't expose the GA ID to web-crawlers. This won't completely remove Referral spam, but it does reduce it.